# Returning random rows from mysql database without using rand()

Tags: php, mysql, random

I would like to be able to pull back 15 or so records from a database. I've seen that using `WHERE id = rand()` can cause performance issues as my database gets larger. All solutions I've seen are geared towards selecting a single random record. I would like to get multiples.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to do this for large databases?

edit:

**Further Edit and Testing:**

I made a fairly simple table, on a new database using MyISAM. I gave this 3 fields: `autokey` (unsigned auto number key) `bigdata` (a large blob) and `somemore` (a medium int). **I then applied random data to the table and ran a series of queries using Navicat. Here are the results:**

`Query 1: select * from test order by rand() limit 15`

```
 Query 2: select * 
          from 
      test 
          join 
      (select round(rand()*(select max(autokey) from test)) as val from test limit 15)                                           as rnd
      on 
          rnd.val=test.autokey;`
```

(I tried both select and select distinct and it made no discernible difference)

and:

```
Query 3 (I only ran this on the second test):
SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
            @lim := 10
    FROM    test
    ) vars
    STRAIGHT_JOIN
    (
    SELECT  r.*,
            @lim := @lim - 1
    FROM    test r
    WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
            AND RAND(20090301) < @lim / @cnt
    ) i
```

```
ROWS:            QUERY 1:               QUERY 2:         QUERY 3:
2,060,922          2.977s                 0.002s            N/A

3,043,406          5.334s                 0.001s            1.260
```

I would like to do more rows so I can see how query 3 scales, but at the moment, **it seems as though the clear winner is query 2**.

Before I wrap up this testing and declare an answer, and while I have all this data and the test environment set up, **can anyone recommend any further testing?**

Comment: These might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142242/what-is-the-best-way-to-pick-a-random-row-from-a-table-in-mysql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868102/order-by-rand-alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 15
```

Another (and possibly more efficient way) would be to join against a set of random values. This should work, if there's some contiguous integer key in the table. Here is how I would do it in **postgres** (My MySQL is a bit rusty)

```
select * from table join 
   (select (random()*maxid)::integer as val from generate_series(1,15)) as rnd
   on rand.val=table.id;
```

where maxid is the highest `id`  in `table`. If `id` has an index, then this would mean only 15 index lookup, so its very fast.

**UPDATE**:

Looks like there no such thing as generate_series in MySQL. My fault. We don't need it actually:

```
select * 
from 
 table 
join 
 -- this just returns 15 random numbers. 
 -- I need `table` here only to produce rows for rand()
 (select round(rand()*(select max(id) from table)) as val from table limit 15) as rnd
on 
 rnd.val=table.id;
```

P.S. If I don't want duplicates returned, I can use (select distinct [...]) in the random generator expression.

Answer (score 2):

> **Update**: Check out the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function). It's pure mySQL and even deals with even distribution.

The problem with `id = rand()` or anything comparable in PHP is that you can't be sure whether that particular ID still exists. Therefore, you need to work with `LIMIT`, and that can become slow for large amounts of data.

As an alternative to that, you could try using a loop in PHP.

What the loop does is

- Create a random integer number using `rand()`, with a scope between `0` and the number of records in the database
- Query the database whether a record with that ID exists
- If it exists, add the number to an array
- If it doesn't, go back to step 1
- End the loop when the array of random numbers contains the desired number of elements

this method could cause a lot of queries in a fragmented table, but they should be pretty fast to execute. It *may* be faster than `LIMIT rand()` in certain situations.

The `LIMIT` method, as outlined by @Luther, is certainly the simplest code-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query with all the results or however many limited, then use mysqli_fetch_all followed by:

```
shuffle($a);
$a = array_slice($a, 0, 15);
```

Comment: This is hardly memory-efficient - he's asking about larger amounts of data.

Comment: well he did say he only wanted 15 rows, its dependant on how much the query brings back

Answer (score 0):

For a large dataset doing

```
select * from table order by rand() limit 15
```

can be quite time and memory consuming.

If your data records happen to be numbered you can put and index on the numbering colum and do a

```
select * from table where no >= rand() limit 15
```

Or even better do the random number generation in your application and do

```
select * from table where no >= $rand and no <= $rand+15
```

If your data doesn't change too often, it might be worth to add such a numbering a column to make the selection efficient.

Comment: But that's not really 15 random rows. it's one random row followed by the next 14 rows in the results and will also not work if $rand happens to fall within what turns out to be the final 15 records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL supports nested queries and that operations on the primary key are fast, I'd try something like

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table order by rand() limit 15)
```