# mysql group by uid which uid match another query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want get 10 rand result, which `image !=''`, group by `uid` and these `uid` are the same from `select uid from user_table where type='1'`. but my query only return 2 result. where is the problem?

```
select * from article_table where image!='' 
order by rand() 
group by uid 
in (select uid from user_table where type='1') 
limit 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it with a `join` instead

```
select *
  from article_table at
  join ( select uid
           from user_table
          where type = '1' ) ut
    on at.uid = ut.uid
 where image != ''
 group by at.uid
 order by rand()
 limit 10
```

Or you may want to restrict the number of `uid`s from your `user_table` to make it quicker to begin with:

```
select at.*
  from article_table at
  join ( select uid
           from user_table
          where type = '1'
          order by rand()
          limit 10 ) ut
    on at.uid = ut.uid
 where image != ''
 group by at.uid
 order by rand()
 limit 10
```

I'm assuming here that there are many articles to each user. Although it looks more horrible, the `order by rand()` in the inner select is over a smaller dataset, which'll speed things up and the `order by` in the outer select only has to deal with a smaller number of rows.

Be careful, ordering by a random value can incur a significant performance hit as you have to go through the entire table that matches your where clause. There are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868102/order-by-rand-alternative).

Answer (score 1):

This following query will do it,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   article_table 
WHERE  image!='' 
       AND uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid 
                   FROM   user_table 
                   WHERE  TYPE = '1' 
                   LIMIT  10) 
GROUP  BY uid 
ORDER  BY Rand() 
LIMIT  10
```