# PHP, MySQL: how to select random records without RAND (attempt to avoid RAND())

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

Because of a huge table I cannot use MySQL function `RAND()` and trying to avoid using `RAND()` this way:

```
$a = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM table WHERE category_id='".$var."'"));
$id = rand($a[0],$a[1]);
$id2 = rand($a[0],$a[1]);
```

Which doesn't work, because: in `$a` I have the biggest and smallest ID with the respective `category_id` - that's ok.

The problem brings the rows with `$id` and `$id2` - because there are used the minimal and maximal ID values, but PHP function `rand()` will take some random value between minimum and maximum - and there is a big probability, that the picked out record will not belongs into `category_id`.

So I would like to ask you about a way, how could I fix this example.

THank you

Comment: But the answer in that question was to use `ORDER BY RAND()`, which he says is not a workable solution for him.

Comment: @Barmar, read the accepted answer to the end. `ORDER BY RAND()` is mentioned only to say that there is a better way, which works for any table whose size is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(
    mysql_query(
      "SELECT count(*) as count FROM table WHERE category_id='$var'"));

$randomrow = rand(0, $row['count'] -1);

$q = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE category_id='$var'
  LIMIT 1 OFFSET $randomrow");
```

Comment: [Why does RAND() cause MySQL to overload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009060/why-does-added-rand-cause-mysql-to-overload) - if you order by something that has to be computed for each row, you will need to spend time to compute it and memory to store it.

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. Adjusted my answer :)