# Howto query for random rows?

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alerternative to MySQL Order By Rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/alerternative-to-mysql-order-by-rand)

What is an efficient way to query for random result sets in the following scenarios:

- Select a single random row from many.
- Select (at least) *n* random rows from many.
- Select all rows in a random order.

In particular interested in MySQL, but might be a reason to try out anything else.

(Primary key is a dense AUTO_INCREMENT integer.)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/alerternative-to-mysql-order-by-rand

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As OMG Ponies pointed out: [This doesn't scale at all.](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2008/06/07/fetching-random-rows-of-mysql-efficiently) Thanks, OMG.

Try using

```
ORDER BY RAND()
```

So...

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: No, it doesn't. It is readable and does return random rows, though. I'd be interested in seeing the benchmark results (your link in the other question is dead).

Comment: Linky: http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2008/06/07/fetching-random-rows-of-mysql-efficiently

Comment: @jasonbar: NP, lucky it was still in my browser cache.

Comment: The catch with the approach in the link is that it assumes you are using a integer primary key.

Comment: Btw, I realize that the OP stated that the PK was an integer, however, a better solution would be one that is generalized to not depend on the PK being a single column and of type integer.