# MySQL Rating system (calculating average from two tables)

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables, `videos` and `videos_ratings`. The videos table has an int `videoid` field (and many others but those fields are not important I think) and many records. The `videos_ratings` table has 3 int fields: `videoid`, `rating`, `rated_by` which has many records (multiple records for each fields from the `videos` table) but not for all records from the `videos` table.

Currently I have the following mysql query:

```
  SELECT `videos`.*, avg(`videos_ratings`.`vote`) 
    FROM `videos`, `videos_ratings` 
   WHERE `videos_ratings`.`videoid` = `videos`.`videoid` 
GROUP BY `videos_ratings`.`videoid` 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 12
```

It selects all the records from table `videos` that have a rating in table video_ratings and calculates the average correctly. But what I need is to select all records from the `videos` table, no matter if there is a rating for that record or not. And if there aren't any records in the `videos_ratings` table for that particular `videos` record, the average function should show 0.

Hope someone could understand what I want... :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
   SELECT v.*,
          COALESCE(x.avg_vote, 0)
     FROM VIDEOS v
LEFT JOIN (SELECT vr.videoid,
                  AVG(vr.vote) AS avg_vote
             FROM VIDEO_RATINGS vr
         GROUP BY vr.videoid) x ON x.videoid = v.videoid
 ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 12
```

Be aware that `ORDER BY RAND()` does not scale well - see [this question for better alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/alerternative-to-mysql-order-by-rand).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a LEFT JOIN to include all records from the videos table, even if there's no rating.

You can then put an if() in your select to turn a NULL rating to 0.