# MySQL vs PHP when retrieving a random item

Tags: php, mysql

which is more efficient (when managing over 100K records):

**A. Mysql**

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY RAND();
```

of course, after that i would already have all the fields from that  record.

**B. PHP**

use memcached to have $cache_array hold all the data from "SELECT id_user FROM user ORDER BY id_user" for 1 hour or so... and then:

$id = array_rand($cache_array);

of course, after that i have to make a MYSQL call with:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id_user = $id;
```

so... which is more efficient? **A** or **B**?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/alerternative-to-mysql-order-by-rand

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It's similar, but not a dupe. He's not asking for the best way to implement it within Mysql, he's asking for a comparison of two methods.

Comment: According to this graph (see link at end), ~100K sorted by RAND() is sub second.  I'm curious to see if PHP (much less .NET or J2EE) will provide similar performance: http://stuff.dasprids.de/images/benchmark-random-row-full.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper way to answer this kind of question is to do a benchmark. Do a quick and dirty implementation each way and then run benchmark tests to determine which one performs better.

Having said that, `ORDER BY RAND()` is known to be slow because it's impossible for MySQL to use an index. MySQL will basically run the `RAND()` function once for each row in the table and then sort the rows based on what came back from `RAND()`.

Your other idea of storing all `user_id`s in memcached and then selecting a random element form the array might perform better if the overhead of memcached proves to be less than the cost of a full table scan. If your dataset is large or staleness is a problem, you may run into issues though. Also you're adding some complexity to your application. I would try to look for another way.

I'll give you a third option which might outperform both your suggestions: Select a `count(user_id)` of the rows in your user table and then have php generate a random number between 0 and the result of `count(user_id)` minus 1, inclusive. Then do a `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1 OFFSET random-number-generated-by-php;`.

Again, the proper way to answer these types of questions is to benchmark. Anything else is speculation.

Comment: this would work great, except that i forgot to specify that the records that can be selected must be filtered with a WHERE flg_pic=1. If i do a count(id_user) the records that have flg_pic=0 would also be considered :s

Comment: @andufo: This is not really a problem at all. You can do `SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM user WHERE flg_pic=1;` and then `SELECT * FROM user WHERE flg_pic=1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET random-number-generated-by-php;`.

Comment: FYI: I realized that the random number must be between `0` and `count(user_id) - 1` inlcusive, and *not* between `1` and `count(user_id)` as I originally stated. I updated my answer. Just wanted to bring that to your attention to avoid a bug.

Comment: @Asaph wow... these are the results with 150k records: OFFSET took 0.0017 secs and BY RAND() took 1.6337 sec -- Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this method won't work when dealing with a table that does not have continuous IDs.  You could end up selecting a value that does not exist.

Comment: @Benjam: You're wrong. This method _will_ work with non-continuous ids because it uses the `OFFSET` to choose the random row, _not_ a specific id.

Comment: @Asaph, seems you are correct, thanks for enlightening me.  I must have read it too fast.

Answer (score 4):

The first one is incredibly slow because

> MySQL creates a temporary table with
>   all the result rows and assigns each
>   one of them a random sorting index.
>   The results are then sorted and
>   returned.

It's elaborated more on [this blog post](http://www.akinas.net/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$random_no = mt_rand(0, $total_record_count);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY __KEY__ LIMIT {$random_no}, 1";
```