# Is there a way to get 2 rows from each group of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I select a fixed number of rows for each group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886064/how-do-i-select-a-fixed-number-of-rows-for-each-group)

For example... if I have this table (sorted by color):

```
--------------
| id | color |
--------------
| 95 | red   |
| 7  | red   |
| 44 | red   |
| 46 | red   |
| 49 | red   |
| 24 | green |
| 37 | green |
| 91 | green |
| 88 | green |
| 44 | blue  |
| 10 | blue  |
| 11 | blue  |
--------------
```

Is there a way for me to get the 2 rows from each color? Example:

```
--------------
| id | color |
--------------
| 7  | red   |
| 44 | red   |
| 24 | green |
| 37 | green |
| 10 | blue  |
| 11 | blue  |
--------------
```

Comment: it doesnt really matter. the 2 with the lowest id would be fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can have something like this,

```
SELECT id, color
FROM   TableName a
WHERE 
(
   SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM   TableName AS f
   WHERE  f.color = a.color AND f.id <= a.id
) <= 2;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/778e5/4)