# rand() faster mysql php function

Tags: php, mysql, function, performance, random

How do I select wallpapers randomly, but cache the last selected one for 10 seconds (for performance reasons)?

the faster RAND() function use Cache in wallpapers or image 
I use this 
but I need to but cache in image timely change after 1 mins or 5 mins to change images in RAND() randoms wallpapers

i use this :

```
$sql_wallpaper = "SELECT SQL_CACHE * FROM `wallpaper` 
                  WHERE wallpaperid >= 
                  (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(wallpaperid) * RAND()) FROM `wallpaper` ) 
                  ORDER BY wallpaperid LIMIT 0,7";
```

but i think its not faster ...
It's not using the cache

Comment: It's hard to determine what you're asking. My best guess is this: "How do I select wallpapers randomly, but cache the last selected one for 5 minutes (for performance reasons)"?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: yes i ask like this images cache and change after 1 min or else use cache in rand()  help?

Answer (score 2):

a) `SQL_CACHE` will be ignored, if the query contains `RAND()`!

b) You will need to save your random id somewhere, e.g. in a database or in apc user data. If using a database you will need to save a timestamp with it, which denotes since then this id is already in use, so you may change it every 5 mins. If using the ladder simply specify a ttl of 5 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming PDO & Memcached:

```
 $pdo; //is the PDO database instance;
 $memcached;//is the memcached instance;

 function _getThe7Wallpapers(){
      global $memcached;
      $cached = $memcached->get('my7wallpapers');
      if($cached!==false) return $cached;
      global $pdo;
      $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM d INTO @count;');
      $pdo->query('SET @stmt = CONCAT(\'SELECT * FROM d ORDER BY id LIMIT \',ROUND(RAND()*GREATEST(@count-7,0)),\',7\');');
      $pdo->query('PREPARE rander FROM @stmt;');
      $rows = $pdo->query('EXECUTE rander;')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $memcached->set('my7wallpapers',$rows,300);//cache for 5 minutes
      return $rows;
 }
```

How to actually set up a PDO instance (or other db-lib) and memcached can be read in the excellent documentation, so I'll leave that up to you as an exercise.

Comment: Its great but its Show one Random wallpaper i need to be 7 wallpaper show, how do that? reply must

Comment: i need it to display LIMIT 0,7  7 random thumbs display 
How?

Comment: It will fetch 7 rows, how and when you alter those rows into some html you like is entirely up to you. The `fetchAll` should return 7 rows of data.

Comment: its fetchAll but Showing only one record please i need to show 6 or 7 record?
how

Comment: @Hassan: I don't know what code does the actual showing, or what coding error you made in those. I'm not here to do the actual work for you. The answer I gave you points you into a possible, it is up to you to debug & adapt it to your needs.

Comment: ok thanks for help  but problem is still finding other way  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

simply `ORDER BY RAND()` in your sql - 
  `SELECT * FROM wallpaper ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,7` then cache the results on the PHP side for X time using any of the described methods from other answers