# Show Random quote from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that holds quotes, i.e Mysql " id,user_who_posted,quote,year,author " I would like to make it show a random quote by id.Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,user_who_posted,quote,year,author 
FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

more randoms at http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id,user_who_posted,quote,year,author FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: If your dataset is huge, consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand