# SQL Random query

Tags: mysql, sql, random

In my MySQL Database all the entries have a rating(an Integer). Now I want to have a SQL query that delivers 10 elements randomly. And as you probably guess, an element's chance to be taken should be RatingOfThisElement/AllRatings. How can I do that. (I know how to do it in php but I'd like to have a SQL query because of the performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google should help you with this: http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Comment: That's just randomly. But I want the chance to be RatingOfThisElement/AllRatings, not 1/NumElements like in your example.

Comment: The point is you need to know how to generate randomness. You need to work out how to apply randomness to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10 such as here [MySQL: Alternatives to ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) but there are issues with ORDER BY RAND in MySQL if used in certain ways. It can case huge performance issues and you may be better off doing it in PHP - [alternatives to ORDER BY RAND](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/)

Comment: That's just randomly,too. But I want the chance to be RatingOfThisElement/AllRatings, not 1/NumElements like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
SELECT * FROM yourtablename ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: If you look at the link I posted that has worse performance than a php query.

Comment: but user1200226 didn't tag PHP ;)