# SQL: how to select randomly and order by higest

Tags: mysql, sql, random

i have a schema look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     point int(255)
    );

INSERT INTO users
(name, point)
VALUES
('Jack', 1),
('Rick', 5),
('Danny', 11),
('Anthony', 24),
('Barla', 3),
('James', 15),
('Melvin', 12),
('Orthon', 5),
('Kenny', 2),
('Smith', 30),
('Steven', 27),
('Darly', 45),
('Peter', 44),
('Parker', 66),
('Lola', 78),
('Jennifer', 94),
('Smart', 87),
('Jin', 64),
('David', 31),
('Jill', 78),
('Ken', 48),
('Martin', 19),
('Adrian', 20),
('Oliver', 16),
('Ben', 100);
```

and my sql is:

```
select id, name, point from users Order by point desc, rand() LIMIT 5
```

problem is, my query does not select 5 row randomly and order them by point. Any idea, how to solve it? here is sqlfiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18f15/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select id,name,point from
(select id, name, point from users Order by rand()  
LIMIT 5) abc
order by point desc;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18f15/10)

Answer (score 2):

*problem is, my query does not select 5 row randomly and order them by point.*

It's because in your given Query you  are using **`ORDER BY`** clause.

```
select id, name, point from users Order by point desc, rand() LIMIT 5
```

Try with removing **point desc,** in **`ORDER BY`** clause

```
select id, name, point from users Order by rand() LIMIT 5
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18f15/5)**

**Edit**

```
select id,name,pont from
(select id, name, point from users Order by rand() LIMIT 5)temp
order by point desc
```

Note: There should be **`no Table`** with name **temp** in you DB (i.e. since you are using it in you **`alias`**)

Comment: `Order by rand()` will be a slow solution when you have a huge table.

Comment: @SaVaFa:any suggestion for rand()?

Comment: @Redbox, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: @SaVaFa, thanks but the query is too complicated. i have 30k row, and this is the resul i use rand():

Showing rows 0 - 27 ( 28 total, Query took 0.1296 sec)