# how to get category wise rendom records with different limit for every category

Tags: mysql, database, random, row, record

I have issue in one mysql query

**Note I have checked all answer plz don't mark this question as repeat**

i have one table with name of "questions" which contain que_id,cat_id, etc fields

I need to fetch 50 records from table which should be random 30 from cat_id=1 and random 20 from cat_id=2

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do it:

```
(SELECT * FROM questions
WHERE cat_id = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 30)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM questions
WHERE cat_id = 2
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20)
```

Comment: thank you but i read "order by rand ()" is performance wise slow..:( is it right?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can search for alternatives to that statement such as: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) or [this other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function). Those questions have already been answered :)

Comment: yes brother it looks like it but not, i need to apply different limit on different category please read my question again..and if you feel its same plz give some brief or give sql query to perform this

Comment: Parentheses were missing. Regarding the previous comment, the issue should be the same for a different limit per category, as I showed you in my answer: 1) Translate any of the answers in the link to satisfy one of the limit and category 2) add UNION ALL 3) use the same query in step 1 change the limit and cat_id

Comment: yes now working fine thank you, it was just parentheses issue, but still i am not getting how to add limit category wise..sorry but better if you can give me mysql query

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE cat_id=2 and que_id >= 
    (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(que_id) * RAND()) FROM `questions` ) ORDER BY que_id LIMIT 20) UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE cat_id=1 and que_id >= 
    (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(que_id) * RAND()) FROM `questions` ) ORDER BY que_id LIMIT 30)
```