# Select attachment_id from one table and user_id in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select 5 random *image* from `phpbb_attachments` and show author username name from `phpbb_users`.

```
phpbb_attachments:        phpbb_topics_posted:        phpbb_users:

attach_id  topic_id       user_id  topic_id           user_id  username
1          10             21       10                 21       Tom
2          5              53       5                  53       Maria
3          15             11       15                 11       John
```

> $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM phpbb3_attachments WHERE
>   mimetype = 'image/jpeg' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff show image attachment and author name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT att.attach_id,
       u.username
FROM phpbb_attachments att
JOIN phpbb_topics_posted t ON (t.topic_id=att.topic_id)
JOIN phpbb_users u ON (u.user_id=t.user_id)
WHERE att.mimetype='image/jpeg'
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5
```

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand), it is best to avoid `ORDER BY RAND()`. Look there for some alternatives.

Also, I only included the fields you showed, you should tweak it to include fields such as file location,etc.

Last, but not least, your example query references phpbb3_attachments, and the sample data uses a different name. You should adjust that accordingly.

Hope this helps.