# LIMIT doesn't always return same number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a table with more than `800K rows`. I'm trying to get random 4 ID's. My query works fast, but it sometimes gives me one, sometimes two and sometimes no results given. Any idea why?

Here is the query:

```
select * from table
  where (ID % 1000) = floor(rand() * 1000)
  AND `type`='5'
  order by rand()
  limit 4
```

the `type='5'` only has `1603` rows and it doesn't always give me 4 rows. when i change it to `type='11'` it works fine. Any idea how to fix this?

here is my code in Yii

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('`t`.`id` % 1000 = floor(rand() * 1000)');
$criteria->compare('`t`.`type`', $this->type);
$criteria->order = 'rand()';
$criteria->limit = 4;

return ABC::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

PS: being a big and growing table, will need a quick query

Comment: If you need a quick query, then don't use `rand` in `MySQL`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously.  There are not necessarily any rows that meet the `where` condition.

One alternative is to dispense with the `where` clause entirely:

```
select t.*
from table t
where `type` = 5
order by rand()
limit 4;
```

Here is a way to make this more efficient (and index on `table(type)` helps):

```
select t.*
from table t cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from table t where type = 5) x
where `type` = 5 and
      rand() <= 5*4 / cnt
order by rand()
limit 4;
```

The "5" is arbitrary.  But it should generally fetch at least four rows.

Answer (score 1):

The rand function is *reiterated for every line*, so you get a Poisson-distribution number of matches. Could be 0, could be 1, could 312 - with different probabilities.

Comment: Can you document the "Poisson-distribution" nature of `rand()`.  I'm pretty sure it is a uniform distribution, and the two are very different.