# Trying to get multiple randomised result returned from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, random

Hi I have spent most of the day on this and turn to you in the hope someone can help. I need to generate a random display 5-10 embedded youtube vids on a page without duplication. I can get the videos to display (but all of the same artist) when I refresh it displays a new set of videos but again all of the same artist. I know the answer is probably very simple but I just can't see it.

Any help or pointers would be most appreciated.

The initial php code is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Youtube FROM artist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (!$result) 
{
    die("Error: Data not found..");
}
$Youtube=$test['Youtube'];
```

With the output being:

```
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?       php echo $Youtube ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $Youtube ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $Youtube ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $Youtube ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $Youtube ?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</ul></div>
```

Comment: This is the initial code:

<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT<?php



$result = mysql_query("SELECT Youtube FROM artist  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!$result) 
  {
  die("Error: Data not found..");
  }
    $Youtube=$test['Youtube'] ;     
    
    
    ?>

Comment: so they are or aren't different videos?

Comment: So, you need to use foreach function with yours $test variable. Like `foreach ($test as $res) {echo $res['Youtube'];})`

Comment: is there more than one artist in the artist table?

Comment: var_dump($test), and var_dump($Youtube); and you might realize something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Alternatives to ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I changed your code and also reduced it by a while loop.

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "database name");
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4'); //optional for when you use utf8mb4 charset (recommended) 


$getYouTubeLinks = "SELECT DISTINCT Youtube FROM artist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
$getRows = $mysqli->query($getYouTubeLinks);


if($getRows->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $getRows->fetch_assoc()) {
    $iframes .= '<iframe width="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$row['Youtube'].'" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>';
    }
  }

  ?>

  <div class="ws_images"><ul>
    <?=$iframes;?>
  </ul></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, unfortunately with your code in place I get:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli 

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

the line it refers to is this piece of code.

 $getRows = $mysqli->query($getYouTubeLinks);

Really do appreciate the help

Comment: hey there, can you show me how you connect to your database without your credentials? Because the `$mysqli` variable is probably not set in your environment Also you should switch to mysqli. The i stands for improved and it's more secure.

Comment: <?php
$servername = "*********";
$username = "**********";
$password = "**********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>

Comment: I updated my answer, try it now with your own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Youtube FROM artist ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5");

[Mysql Documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)