# Loop in PHP taking time, Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, pdo

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in...

```
$level = "1";

$get_question = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Level = :Level ORDER BY RAND()');
$get_question->bindparam(":Level",$level);
$get_question->execute();
$fetch_question=$get_question->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmtpr = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM used WHERE Last=:user_name");
$stmtpr->execute(array(":user_name"=>$fetch_question['Id']));
$rowpr = $stmtpr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($stmtpr->rowCount() > 0)
        {
    $get_questionl = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Level = :Level ORDER BY RAND()');
    $get_questionl->bindparam(":Level",$level);
    $get_questionl->execute();
    $fetch_question=$get_questionl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
```

Execution takes time only when it goes in `loop`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `$stmtpr->rowCount()` never changes, so your loop never ends. You're basically saying:

```
while (10 > 1) { ... }
```

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but it appears you're trying to re-query the same rows you just queried. You probably just want to loop over the original result set.

Also note that `ORDER BY RAND()` is notoriously non-performant. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand) for some alternative ideas.

Comment: Ok, I will look for alternatives.., you said **The value of `$stmtpr->rowCount()` never changes....** how can it be changed in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Add at the top this in your code 
Unlimited execution time

`ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

Also, you can add unlimited memory usage

`ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");`

In your case also change the rowCount() like this

```
  $count = $stmtpr->rowCount();

while($count > 0)
        {
    $get_questionl = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Level = :Level ORDER BY RAND()');
    $get_questionl->bindparam(":Level",$level);
    $get_questionl->execute();
    $fetch_question=$get_questionl->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count--;
        }
```

Comment: What about code, is the code coded correctly? I am having doubt about that!

Comment: @user9836106 
I have  updated my answer and write a comment

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
while($stmtpr->rowCount() > 0)
```

write

```
while($rowpr = $stmtpr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```