# how to fix: Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

This works fine:

```
UPDATE users 
        SET group_id = (SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City FROM users WHERE scope IS NULL AND health_facility_id = 10) 
WHERE scope IN ('MHO', 'Mayor', 'Doctor') AND health_facility_id = 10;
```

With this i get an ERROR:

```
UPDATE users 
        SET group_id = (SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City FROM users WHERE scope IS NULL AND health_facility_id = (SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City FROM users WHERE scope IS NULL)) 
WHERE scope IN ('MHO', 'Mayor', 'Doctor') AND health_facility_id = (SELECT health_facility_id FROM users WHERE scope IS NULL);
```

but this

```
(SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City FROM users WHERE scope IS NULL)
```

query is returning many data. What I want to achieve is to update multiple rows in Column group_id. see this image https://i.imgur.com/aNSsWie.png

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results would all help.

Comment: question is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any more criteria to limit the citys. 
do something like this.

```
UPDATE users 
SET group_id = (SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City 
                FROM users 
                WHERE scope IS NULL 
                 AND health_facility_id = (SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City 
                                           FROM users 
                                          WHERE scope IS NULL
                                          ORDER BY Prov_Current_Address_City
                                          Limit 1)
                ORDER BY Prov_Current_Address_City
                Limit 1) 
WHERE scope IN ('MHO', 'Mayor', 'Doctor') 
AND health_facility_id = (SELECT health_facility_id 
                          FROM users 
                          WHERE scope IS NULL
                          ORDER BY health_facility_id 
                          Limit 1);
```

Comment: Update to a more or less random value, instead of correcting the bug?

Comment: How to select by random ordering look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand

Comment: i tried your answer but still same result

Comment: @Claude try this new approach, now all only select querys return only 1 row., if this also doesn't work you have to build in dbfiddle.uk an example database, because i believe you can eventually group the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just change = to IN when a subquery returns more than one row. If you were not expecting the subqueries to return more than one row then you need to fix your original query.

```
UPDATE users 
SET group_id =
    (
    SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City
    FROM users
    WHERE scope IS NULL
    AND health_facility_id IN
        (
        SELECT Prov_Current_Address_City
        FROM users
        WHERE scope IS NULL
        )
    ) 
WHERE scope IN ('MHO', 'Mayor', 'Doctor')
AND health_facility_id IN
    (
    SELECT health_facility_id
    FROM users
    WHERE scope IS NULL
    );
```

Comment: same result not working