# Rand in high tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a sql table with a very high number of rows (for example 300 million of rows).

Each row have an text field and I'd like to retrieve 10 rows randomly.

The problem is that using

```
select key from the_table where enabled=1 order by rand() limit 10
```

Calculate the rand value and order all the rows by that value is a very high load.

Is there some way for avoiding that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [quick selection of a random row from a large table in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211329/quick-selection-of-a-random-row-from-a-large-table-in-mysql) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594483/optimizing-my-mysql-statement-rand-too-slow

Comment: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: +1 I love the question, so far all answer haven't been perfect, in your problem you warranted random without repeating, all answer repeating is possible... so there is not a solution yet @EvanMulawski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can generate the keys outside of SQL (even if it takes using 15-20 to get 10 that are enabled) you can then skip the order() which is almost certainly what the problem is wrt to load

SELECT key WHERE key IN [x,y,z....]

where x,y,z are generated randomly and externally.

Even better, you can create a table of enabled keys, sorted randomly and just page through that in chunks of 10. You'd need to update it occasionally and there's a penalty in space but that's probably not THAT big a deal.

There's more sophisticated solutions, but that would get you moving.

Answer (score 1):

I'd test (time) the possible solutions to verify they are indeed as slow as you suspect.

If your primary keys are sequential or otherwise predicatable, perhaps you could generate 10 random ones from code or as part of a procedure, then `SELECT` the 10 records by key.

For example, if your keys were sequential numeric IDs, then you'd generate 10 `RAND` numbers between `Min(ID)` and `Max(ID)` and use `WHERE Id in (rand1, rand2, rand3 ...)`

Comment: @wildor but it's possible that he could repeat values

Comment: @jcho360 depends on how the random numbers are generated. One way is to generate the whole set and randomise the order, then take the top `x` many results that you need.