# Optimize query to make Order by random run faster

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my rails app I have a method that looks like this:

```
def find_person(field, attribute)
  Person.where.not(Hash[field, nil])
      .where.not("lower(#{field})  = ?", attribute.downcase)
      .where("difference(#{field}, ?) < 2", attribute)
      .order('RANDOM()')
      .limit(3)
      .pluck("lower(#{field})")
      .uniq
end
```

This query is very slow because of `.order('RANDOM()')`. How can I make this query faster?

Comment: Will this question be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594483/optimizing-my-mysql-statement-rand-too-slow

Comment: Try limiting the list of randoms first. Here is a pretty good [Step by Step Article](https://www.periscope.io/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster.html) on how this works and how to implement.

Comment: some more links http://www.depesz.com/2007/09/16/my-thoughts-on-getting-random-row/ and http://blog.rhodiumtoad.org.uk/2009/03/08/selecting-random-rows-from-a-table/

Comment: can you post an "explain analyze"? the reason is: "order by random()" cannot make use of presorted data using an index. therefore it is slow. you cannot index on random values .

Comment: @engineersmnky - Awesome article, thanks. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function/25882872

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, use Ruby to get the 3 random records.

```
def find_person(field, attribute)
  ids = Person.where.not(Hash[field, nil])
      .where.not("lower(#{field})  = ?", attribute.downcase)
      .where("difference(#{field}, ?) < 2", attribute)
      .pluck("id")

  Person.where(:id => ids.sample(3))
end
```

If pluck is too slow, another approach.

```
def find_person(field, attribute)
  q = Person.where.not(Hash[field, nil])
    .where.not("lower(#{field})  = ?", attribute.downcase)
    .where("difference(#{field}, ?) < 2", attribute)

  max = q.count
  offsets = [rand(max), rand(max), rand(max)]
  offsets.map { |o| q.offset(o).limit(1).pluck("lower(#{field})").first }

end
```

Comment: You may be able to cache that.

Comment: Added another approach to avoid the id array.