# unique shop id in doctrine query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
 $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')
                    ->from("ShopMainBundle:ShopPicture", 'p')
                    ->innerJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
                    ;
```

I wanted to get the pictures from each unique shop. How do I do this? In other words I want to specify that each p should belong to X.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but the following should work:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('shop', 'p')
                ->from("ShopMainBundle:Shop", 'shop')
                ->innerJoin('s.pictures', 'p')
                ->getQuery()
                ;
foreach ($query->getResult() as $shop) {
    foreach ($shop->getPictures() as $picture) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to get one picture for every shop, you can group by the shop:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('p')
                ->from("ShopMainBundle:ShopPicture", 'p')
                ->groupBy('p.shop')
                ;
```

You however cannot get one random picture since Doctrine does not support `RAND()`. See [How to select randomly with doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine) for more info

Comment: well..I'd want to do it inside the query.. essentially I wanted to get pictures from unique shops

Comment: Could you maybe provide us with the raw SQL you're trying to create? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't even know how to do it using RAW SQL.. Basically I wanted to get one random picture from each unique shops that is in the database.. if that makes any sense. The relationship is that a shop can have many pictures