# Why isn't RAND() working for doctrine2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

We had this query on our DB (5 million records)

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

of course it was slow (2.7 seconds)

so we optimized the query to this (instead of ordering 5 million records it picks 100 and orders them):

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE RAND() < 0.00001
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

The query time is 0.002 seconds now

For a Symfony2 project we need to get this running on doctrine

```
public function findAllRandom()
{
   return $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE RAND() < 0.0001 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20')
    ->getResult();
}
```

But it throws this error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 48: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'RAND'

I doesn't seem to know the RAND function

This is a query that would work (if it helps)

```
   public function findAllRandom()
    {
       return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE p.upvotes > 3')
        ->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select randomly with doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explain the `RAND()` function to Doctrine. Note that the `EntityManager`'s `createQuery` expects DQL, not SQL, and Doctrine does not know how to treat it, because probably it's not supported by all the Doctrine's DB backends.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine#answer-10762751), it has all the info on implementing `RAND()` in Doctrine manually.