# How to select randomly with Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, symfony

I want to select one random document from **MongoDB** collection. If I'd used MySQL, my solution would be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine#answer-27604826).

How can I select a random document from MongoDB Collection using **Doctrine ODM** query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem in this way:

```
public function getRandomUser()
{
    $qb = $this->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder('AppBundle:User');
    $count =  $qb->getQuery()->count();
    $skip_count = random_int(0, $count);
    $qb->skip($skip_count);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// Create Query Builder.
$dm = $this->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder('Document');

// Count documents.
$count = $dm->getQuery()->execute()->count();

// Get random number not exceeding $count variable.
$random = mt_rand(0, $count);

// Query for document with skip.
$random_document = $dm->skip($random)
                      ->getQuery()
                      ->getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you Mongo server is 3.2 or later, you can use $sample aggregation command:

```
$ab = $this->dm->createAggregationBuilder(User::class);
$ab->sample($count);

return $ab->hydrate(User::class)->execute();
```

Keep in mind that result set can contains not unique elements, additional reading about $sample https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#behavior

For old Mongo servers you should set random value to every document when persisting and use $lt-$gt query to fetch random set, please refer to [Random record from MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
public function getRandomDocument()
{
    $qb = $this->getDocumentManager()->createQueryBuilder('YourBundle:TargetDocument');
    $count =  $qb->getQuery()->count();
    $skip_count = random_int(0, $count);
    $qb->skip($skip_count);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```