# Symfony doctrine DQL random result in Query with MaxResult

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I get a random result with an dql Query?

This is my query:

```
$firstCategoryId = 50;

$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(BaseProduct::class);

        $products = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->join('p.categories', 'c')
            ->where('c.id = :categoryId')
            ->setParameter('categoryId', $firstCategoryId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults(4)
            ->getResult();
```

This returns me always the first 4 products.
Lets say the category with ID 50 has over 100 products. And what I want is querying randomly 4 articles from category with ID 50. But how? Is this possible? Of course I can set no Max Result and than do it with PHP... but this is not a good solution because of performance.

Comment: If you don't really care about speed, you can try to get all the products, shuffle the results array and then get the first 4 elements.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine), this is already answered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select randomly with doctrine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create dql function for that. https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/919465 you can check that.

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

class RandFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'RAND()';
    }
}
```

After that open your config.yml file and add autoload that RandFunction.

```
orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                Rand: Acme\Bundle\DQL\RandFunction
```

And your query must be like:

```
$firstCategoryId = 50;

$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(BaseProduct::class);

        $products = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->join('p.categories', 'c')
            ->addSelect('RAND() as HIDDEN rand')
            ->where('c.id = :categoryId')
            ->orderBy('rand')
            ->setParameter('categoryId', $firstCategoryId)
            ->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults(4)
            ->getResult();
```