# Doctrine DQL random row?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I am trying to get a random row from my table. I found this `SQL` example:

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Is it possible to do it in pure `DQL` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select randomly with doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762538/how-to-select-randomly-with-doctrine)