# Mysql: 'order by Rand() Limit 4 ' or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to extract random 4 items from latest news database.

Since this table has a lot of rows, is it wise to do so with order by RAND() or its waste of resources ? As it will go throgh the whole table and reorder it.

Is there any better way to do it , extract random featured items from table with hundreds of rows ?

**Example:**

```
$l=$database->query("SELECT car,price,thumbnail FROM cardb WHERE type='new' order by RAND() LIMIT 4");
foreach($l as $l){print_r($l);}
```

Thankx for taking time to answer
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I would do this in two queries. Get random row numbers:

```
SELECT
    floor(count * rand()) r1,
    floor(count * rand()) r2,
    floor(count * rand()) r3,
    floor(count * rand()) r4
FROM
    (SELECT count(*) count FROM cardb WHERE type = 'new') c
```

And get rows:

```
SELECT car, price, thumbnail FROM cardb WHERE type = 'new' LIMIT {r1}, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT car, price, thumbnail FROM cardb WHERE type = 'new' LIMIT {r2}, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT car, price, thumbnail FROM cardb WHERE type = 'new' LIMIT {r3}, 1
UNION ALL
SELECT car, price, thumbnail FROM cardb WHERE type = 'new' LIMIT {r4}, 1
```

Comment: That query may have duplicates in the result set. `ORDER BY RAND()` won't.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Yeah but I don't think it's a big problem in this case. Otherwise we can generate unique random numbers at the PHP side. In any case I think this is one of the most resource-savy solution.