# Randomizing results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm making a raffle program and I want the person's name to be random but not repeat any records. I'm selecting between the two queries below. The first one is sure that no record is repeated from the returned result but sacrifices the people with higher id's since they will not be selected. The second one is by random but might select repeated records. Is there any other way I can achieve random records in mysql or in php without repeating any of the returned results?

```
$select_random = $db->get_results("SELECT person FROM tbl_people WHERE state = 1  LIMIT $offset, 30");

$select_random = $db->get_results("SELECT participant FROM tbl_participants WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY RAND()");
```

Comment: No, the second definitly does not select duplicate results.

Comment: On a side note: `ORDER BY RAND()` is notoriously expensive. If your table grows [this question might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about adding `DISTINCT`

```
$select_random = $db->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT person FROM tbl_people WHERE state = 1  LIMIT $offset, 30");
```

or

```
$select_random = $db->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT participant FROM tbl_participants WHERE state = 1 ORDER BY RAND()");
```