# How can I get a random order of returned rows in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL query, that returns set of rows. What I need is to get them in random order, each time that the query is executed.

For example, I have query

```
SELECT id,id_banner,name FROM module_banner
```

And it returns me 3 rows with ids - 1,2,3

I want to get them in random order - 3,2,1    2,3,1    1,3,2  and so on.

Let me know if the question is not clear

P.S.

Is there solution without RANDOM() function ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Comment: This is demo query. The one I use is complex and  RAND() will cause slow perfomance

Comment: _why_ do you need random results?  What is the rest of your situation like - there may be a better way to get the results you need.  Please note that, in SQL, unless an `ORDER BY` statement is specified, your results _are_ 'random' - you will not be able to guarantee the order of the returned results.

Comment: In order to generate a random query result order, you need -- at the very least -- one "random" number. How do you propose generating a pseudo random number without RAND()? Do you have another language available?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `ORDER BY RAND()`:

```
SELECT id,id_banner,name FROM module_banner ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `ORDER BY RAND()` at the end of your query.

Query in-general will be

`SELECT field1, field2, ... , field(n) FROM TableName ORDER BY RAND()`

In your case it would be

`SELECT id, id_banner, name FROM module_banner ORDER BY RAND()`

### Update 1

While searching I found one article & You should read this article : **["Do not use ORDER BY RAND() or How to get random rows from table?"](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/)**

Comment: It is not acceptable for me. In this article, he use generated numbers in LIMIT, but I have my own limit and I can't replace it with this numbers to generate random rows. But thanks for that info.

Comment: @Ahmed: can you tell the scenario that you have and what you want to achieve?? Maybe that way we can help you out...

Comment: There is sql query executed on a few tables with limit of rows. Actually query returns banners. Count of returned rows can be limited ( for example 10), banners displayed on the page in different order, each time page loaded

Comment: edit question and add this info there so that all can read there... sorry for not informing earlier. Whatever info related to question should come in question...

Comment: which language are you using for front-end?? In PHP you have `shuffle`. I java you can use random etc...

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id,id_banner,name
  FROM module_banner JOIN
       (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
                    (SELECT MAX(id)
                       FROM module_banner)) AS id
        ) AS r2
       USING (id);
```

[Reference](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)