# Select optimised random results from a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, random

I want to use the "order by rand alternative" query (bottom)  to get a random set of results but I want to get them from within the results a query such as:

```
SELECT t2.id FROM index_table t1 JOIN data_table t2 ON t1.id= t2.index_id
```

And I need to limit the number of random results I'd get back.
I can't quite get my head around the syntax I'd need to use, any help greatly appreciated.

thanks

"order by rand alternative" query:

[How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 10
        FROM    t_random
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  r.*,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM    t_random r
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND(20090301) < @lim / @cnt
        ) i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      t2.id 
   FROM 
      index_table t1 
         JOIN data_table t2 
            ON t1.id= t2.index_id
   ORDER BY
     RAND()
   LIMIT 5
```

or whatever the maximum number of entries you want via the limit

Comment: I wanted to use the optimised method quoted and linked in the post not  order by rand as it is too inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  @cnt := COUNT(*) + 1,
                @lim := 10
        FROM    FROM index_table t1 JOIN data_table t2 ON t1.id= t2.index_id
        ) vars
STRAIGHT_JOIN
        (
        SELECT  t2.id,
                @lim := @lim - 1
        FROM index_table t1 JOIN data_table t2 ON t1.id= t2.index_id
        WHERE   (@cnt := @cnt - 1)
                AND RAND() < @lim / @cnt
        ) i
```

I removed the parameter from RAND otherwise my output was always the same.