# Mysql Query Taken Long Time

Tags: mysql, optimization

My table `tbltemp` has around 9 lakhs records. The columns are: `id` (primary key, autoincrement), `name`, `qty`, `price`, `status`, `mod_date`, `created_date`.

My query is:

```
SELECT * 
 FROM tbltemp 
 WHERE qty > 3 
 ORDER By Rand() 
 LIMIT 50
```

It takes around 7 to 10 seconds to execute. How can I optimize my table or query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Comment: Why do you have to do `ORDER By Rand()` here?

Comment: How long does query `select * from tbltemp where qty > 3 ORDER By id Limit 50` takes?

Comment: @Interrobang Not quite - the other question limits result to one row, while here are multiple rows. Solution found there is not applicable here.

Comment: You might take a look at [this article](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/).

Answer (score 0):

You should create ad index on `qty` column.
Anyway `ORDER By Rand()` is time consuming...

Comment: That will be a optional good thing but not needed at all. I am sure if he runs the query `select * from tbltemp where qty > 3 ORDER By id Limit 50` ... will be much faster.

Comment: I want to show the random list when each time user refresh my page..thats why i use the "ORDER BY RAND()" in query @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for `order by rand()`. Try this once and see if it works

```
select @lims := floor(1+rand()*(count(*) - 1)) from tbltemp;  

PREPARE mystatement FROM "SELECT * FROM tbltemp WHERE qty > 3 LIMIT ?, 50";

EXECUTE mystatement USING @lims;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query :

```
SELECT * FROM tbltemp WHERE qty > 3 ORDER By Rand() LIMIT 50
```

For query optimization please take a look :

1. ORDER BY clause is the main reason for taking long time.
2. Add an Index to `qty` column.
3. Also the storage engine you are using can also affect the performance 
   optimization of query.MYISAM is the fastest storage engine.