# fetch randomly record in php from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch randomly record from a mysql table. I know we can fetch using order by rand() but its seems to be slow process for large field. can we have some other way to fetch rand records.

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a rand offset first by

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS rnd FROM your_table
```

Then select a record by using the offset.

Answer (score 2):

If you have some primary key `Id` you can pick a random number between `MIN(Id)` and `MAX(Id)` and get that item. Simply try again if the item with that `Id` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name
FROM random JOIN
     (SELECT CEIL(RAND() *
             (SELECT MAX(id)
              FROM random)) AS id
     ) AS r2
     USING (id);
```

Your question is already answered here:

[How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  table 
join 
  (select round(rand()*(select max(id) from table)) as val from table) as rnd
on rnd.val=table.id;
```