# Displaying random mysql records - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to display a random record from my table but with no luck this is what I have upto. This is coded in PHP

```
$range_result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX() AS max_id , MIN() AS min_id FROM pages");
$range_row = mysql_fetch_object( $range_result ); 
$random = mt_rand($range_row->min_id , $range_row->max_id);
$result_random = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id >= $random LIMIT 0,1");
echo $result_random;
```

Wondering if this is an obvious mistake? I have connected to the database fine.

JB

Comment: You could try adding "order by RAND()" however this is know to demand a fair bit more processing by the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function

Comment: Check for sql errors using mysql_query's return value and mysql_error()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do this with straight SQL with a `mysqli_multi_query` for performance:

```
// First query gets the random ID, second gets the associated row
$sql = "SELECT @id:=FLOOR(RAND()*(MAX(id) - MIN(id))) + MIN(id) FROM pages; 
        SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = @id;"

// Create a mysqli object and execute the multi-query
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
$result = $mysqli->store_result();

// Grab the first row from the first resultset
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I think the downvote came from the initial post that had WHERE ORDER BY in a mysql_ function. Not sure though

Comment: Pretty sure WHERE ORDER BY would cause an error, and mysql_ always gets attacked on this site. Just saying... wasn't me though.

Comment: Ah, missed that... was a little sloppy, indeed.  But my edited answer is good... AND it's tested this time. ;)

Comment: @TheSmose aww, here, you earned it.

Comment: Perfect thanks @TheSmose. A quick last question, how would I echo out the title instead of the ID of that record *field is called page_title* :)

Comment: @JBUCL - just change `print_r($row);` to `echo $row['page_title'];`

Comment: I receive - defined index: page_title? :(

Comment: @JBUCL that makes no sense - is `page_title` an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use rand():

```
"SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY RAND() Limit 1"
```

But to answer, what is the MIN and MAX selecting if not defined? Should you perhaps try:

```
"SELECT MAX(`id`) AS max_id , MIN(`id`) AS min_id FROM pages"
```

And I don't think you need the offset in the limit. So just LIMIT 1 would probably be fine.

As the comments state, RAND() might be slow for larger data sets, but in many cases this is not a problem and the lag is minimal unless you have an exceptional amount of data. Read frank's link to see details. Personally, though, I've never really had a problem on RAND() speed.

And as Michael said, you should probably try to fetch the results before echoing what you believe to be the result set.

And also, mysql_ functions are deprecated. You should switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Comment: only ok for a small data set

Comment: +1 because `ORDER BY RAND()` is a simple working solution for many applications where you don't have huge tables.

Answer (score 0):

While you would be much better off ordering by RAND(), your method would work.  Your problem is that you're trying to echo out a mysql result set.  You need to do something like this after your code:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_random);
echo $row['field1'] . " " . $row['field2'];
```

Where field1 and field2 are names of columns in your table.