# MySQL select from multiple identical tables and display results randomly with php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I would like to query multiple identical tables in my db which has different prefixes and than display the results randomly but somehow I need to track the origin of the item and I couldn't figure out how

I do the query like this because I don't have access to information_schema

```
$query = "SHOW TABLES FROM mydb WHERE RIGHT( tables_in_mydb, 5 ) = 'table'";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_num_rows($res);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {

$numbers = explode('_', $row[0]);

  if($num > 0) {
    $q = "SELECT `this`, `that`, `something` FROM ".$numbers[0]."_idetinticaltables"; // :)
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while($c = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
       /*display the results randomly with an identifier where the come from*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: store the $numbers[0] somewhere, since that's what tells you which table the data came from.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ORDER BY RAND()  to randomly sort it

Comment: its a good idea but it will randomise only table by table if I print the results out than it will look like this: table1 in random order, table2 in random order, tableX in random order, and I would like to randomise the complete result like: table4, table1, table3, table2

Comment: Well, you can't use ORDER BY on SHOW TABLES, so you would need to put the references to an array and then use shuffle($ar) on those names and  use a loop to display also randomized results. How does that sound?

Answer (score 0):

```
$aa=array()   
while($c = mysql_fetch_array($r)) 
{
   /*display the results randomly with an identifier where the come from*/
   $aa[]=$c;
}
echo $aa; // print "Array"
```

Comment: myabe I'm wrong but if you echo $aa outside the loop than it will print only the first item of the array.

Comment: @LaciK: Well, it just outputs `Array` and that's it. Not an answer, don't bother with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work:

1. Get the list of the tables you're interested in. You already do that.
2. Create a [`UNION` of multiple `SELECT` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html). Each `SELECT` statement differs for the table being selected from and you add a column set to the name of the table (so you can identify it later):

   ```
   (SELECT *, TABLENAME = 'first_name_of_table' FROM first_name_of_table ...)
   UNION
   (SELECT *, TABLENAME = 'second_name_of_table' FROM second_name_of_table ...)
   UNION
   ...
   ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
   ```
3. Because it is a `UNION` you can randomize the whole order then. See [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1244555/367456) because it is not that trivial to do well, the example above is *only* to have an `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clause placed there. With many entries in your tables, it will kill your server.