# Get data from sql in one array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to get the data from database in one single array but I was unsuccessful doing that. What I have tried is -

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM meaning ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");
$gt = mysql_fetch_array($q);
var_dump($gt);
```

This query fetches only one row. What I want is that this query should fetch random 7 rows and come back in one array as data like -

```
array(4) { [0]=> row_0
           [1]=> row_1
           [2]=> row_2
           [3]=> row_3
           [4]=> row_4
           [5]=> row_5
           [6]=> row_6
         }
```

Comment: try mysql_fetch_assoc($q) instead mysql_fetch_array($q);

Comment: First, `mysql_` is deprecated, please switch to `mysqli_` or `PDO`. ^^  Secondly, you can, but you have to create a loop.  From the function [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php). So do a `while` or `for` loop while using it to get all the rows.

Comment: @AwladLiton That won't help, instead of returning a numerically indexed array for each row, it will return an associative one.

Comment: Actually, if you use mysqli_fetch_array the returned array has characteristics numeric and associative arrays.  Not certain if mysql_fetch_array does, though

Comment: [note about ORDER BY RAND() performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330798/mysql-order-by-rand-performance-issue-and-solution)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no function in the `mysql` extension that does what you want. All the `mysql_fetch_XXX` functions read just one row at a time. To get everything, you have to use a loop:

```
$gt = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $gt[] = $row;
}
var_dump($gt);
```

If you convert to the PDO extension, it has the method `PDO::fetchAll` that does what you want.

Comment: Yeah, exactly my thoughts. ++

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helps you,

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meaning ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");
 while($gt = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
   $myarray[] =  $gt;
 }   
 var_dump($myarray);
```

Comment: How do you figure this helps?  You are just assigning a row to a defined index in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meaning ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");
$i = 0;
$myarray[]='';

while($gt = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
  $myarray[$i] = $gt;
  $i++;
}

var_dump($myarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns the first row in a MySQL Resource in the form of an associative array. Fetches a result row as an **associative array, a numeric array, or both**.
You need to **use loop** to get all the records.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM meaning ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    echo $row["title"]."<br />";
}
```