# How do I randomly display categories in a particular order

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have an online store where the members can subscribe to any of the 3 packages (1, 2 & 3). Below is a sample of the Products DB table.

```
id    package          product       status
1     3                  Biro          1
2     1                  Paper         1
3     3                  Pin           0
4     2                  Eraser        1
5     2                  Blade         1
6     3                  Bag           1
7     2                  Pen           0
8     1                  Sharpener     1
9     1                  Shoe          1
10    2                  Chair         1
```

I displayed the package 3 products first, then package 2 products next then package 1 products last like this;

```
$get_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='1' ORDER BY package DESC");
```

But what I want to really do is to randomly display all package 3 products first, then randomly display package 2 products and lastly display package 1 products randomly. So that no particular item will always be at the top while some will always be on the bottom.

How do I write the syntax?

Comment: its not random, if its in a particular order

Comment: From a UI standpoint, wouldn't it be a bit haphazard if the location of something was always different for no reason?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sort the products column randomly using only SQL by doing the following:

`$get_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='1' ORDER BY package DESC, RAND()");`

However, please keep in mind ordering by "RAND()" in MySQL can be slow, especially if your columns are not indexed.

See the following links for reference:

[MySQL: Alternatives to ORDER BY RAND()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823306/mysql-alternatives-to-order-by-rand)

[How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

[mysql order by rand() performance issue and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330798/mysql-order-by-rand-performance-issue-and-solution)

Answer (score 0):

First, split the products into groups by package as you fetch your query results:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $packages[$row['package']][] = $row;
}
```

Then shuffle the groups before you output them:

```
foreach ($packages as $package_products) {
    shuffle($package_products);
    foreach ($package_products as $product) {
        // output product
    }
}
```