# Complex MySQL SELECTION

Tags: mysql

Ok guys, im not very good in MySQL, but I can do basics... So now I need some help.
I have two tables - 
questions(where some questions and avaliable answers are stored) and
log(where log from the previus answered question is stored)

questions-

```
questionId,     question,                answer1...balbalba
1              'question balba'         'Avaliable answer1'
2              'question2 blaba'        'Other answer'
```

log-

```
id, questionId, userId
1   1           123456
```

Here is stored that `userId` is answered on `questionId` 1

So I need a query that finds random question from 'questions' that user '123456' isn't answered.
I hope you help me...

Comment: Perhaps looking into `JOIN`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT q.questionId
FROM questions AS q
LEFT OUTER JOIN log AS l ON q.questionId = l.questionId AND l.userId = 123456
WHERE l.id IS NULL
```

This gives you the questions that user 123456 has not answered.

To select one of them at random, append

```
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

to the query.

The problem with `ORDER BY RAND()` is, that it does not scale well. However, the join condition already does a good job in reducing the size of the result set (it gives you at most one result per question). If the number of questions is low (around 100), I would not worry about performance implications of `ORDER BY RAND()`. If you have a lot of questions, have a look at question [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/) for alternatives.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function) for the performance implications of using `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: @hd1 Thanks. I actually suspected that the performance is quite poor.