# Php MySQL Nonrepeating Random Data Display

Tags: php, mysql, random

Let's say I've got a mySQL database: two columns: ID and names, with 100 rows.
What I'd like to do is pick out say 10 names - with no repeats - and display them in random order.

Using this code, I can pick out just one name...

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$rand = rand(1, 100);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE ID=$rand";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sandbox);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) 
{
$name1 = $row['Name'];
echo $name1 . "<br>";
}

?>
```

... what would be the best code to get my 10 random nonrepeating names?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (and fastest for the database) would be to generate ten unique numbers using [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) functions, and then create a query with the IN clause:

```
$numbers = range(1, 100);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = implode( ', ', array_slice($numbers, -10) );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE ID IN ($numbers)";
// example query: 
// SELECT * FROM names WHERE ID IN (63, 76, 69, 59, 9, 84, 60, 18, 23, 62)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of rows in the table, you probably don't want to do `ORDER BY RAND()` as suggested by 4 other people for [performance reasons](http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/avoid-rand-in-mysql):

> The ORDER BY RAND() operation actually re-queries each row of your table, assigns a random number ID and then delivers the results.  This takes a large amount of processing time for table of more than 500 rows.

The recommended approach extends your original idea to get 10 IDs and do a simple select query for those.

If they're sequential, you can just generate a random in that range, or retrieve all the IDs, shuffle them and request the first 10 values.

There are some other suggestions in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT id, name FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: Rather than posting just an SQL snippet, can you provide a description of what it's doing and why? As it stands, this question is flagged as low quality.

Comment: It's doing exactly what Gregory Tippett asked for: get 10 random no-repeating records from database. I think it's clearly, so no need in repeating question in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $sandbox);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
```

Comment: <noob> Sounds good... then how do I go about displaying those names? </noob>

Comment: Just like you were: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) 
{
$name1 = $row['Name'];
echo $name1 . "<br>";
}`

Comment: Ah, woops, missed a semicolon. Thanks.

How would you recommend I integrate this with html if I wanted to style each name individually? (each name getting a unique CSS ID?)

Comment: Why would you do that? There should be some pattern of designing? Styling each record different, will make your page not-so-dynamic, since each new inserted record should have new css styles, so instead of just inserting a new `name` in the database, you will need to open the code again, and style this name. It seems to me a bad practice

Comment: The desired final appearance here is 10 individually styled boxes each with a randomly selected name in it. Those names should not repeat.  

So if you have another suggestion for how to code that I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM names ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```