# Hiding an item if product name doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

As the title says, I want to hide an item is the product name doesn't exist.

The problem here is.. When it show the products for the user, it actually show nothing where the //show nothing is placed instead of showing a new product that has a product name.

So sometime it shows 10 products, sometime it shows 5 products, which is not what i want.

I want it to show a new product if a product name is not there.

Any clues on what i change in my code?

my current code is:

Picks 12 random product from the database:

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");
```

Shows the products for the user:

```
if($product_name == ''){

         //Show nothing

        }else{
    $dynamicList .= 
                '<table border="0" id="indexproducts" style="margin-left:22px; margin-bottom:20px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td id="indexproductfoto" align="center">
                        <a href="http://www.mysite.com/id/'.$id.'/'.$seo8.'/">
                            <img src="http://www.mysite.com/inventoryimages/'.$id.'.jpg" onerror="this.src=\'http://www.mysite.com/inventoryimages/x.jpg\';" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="indexproducttext2"><strong>'.$product_name.'</strong><br />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#F00" id="indexproducttext"><strong>Pris: '.round($price).':-</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="color:#F00" id="indexproducttext"><strong>(Exkl.moms: '.round($price1).':-)</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td id="indexproducttext"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/id/'.$id.'/'.$seo8.'/">Produktinformation</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name <> "" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12

Comment: @iiro Post that as an answer.

Comment: BTW, `ORDER BY RAND()` is usually _not_ a good idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function for an alternative.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I will consider it as an alternative, thanks.

Comment: This works:  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productname <> '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12");    Thanks iiro

Comment: @iiro Is it possible for you to put it as an answer and perhaps put in a small explanation what <> '' does in this query, so i can choose it as an accepted answer?

Comment: @JimSundqvist There you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented

try this SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE IFNULL(productname, "") <> "" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12
```

where the operator `<>` means "not equal" that is same as `!=` So you look for all the products whose name is not empty and whose name is not NULL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: Thanks mate! It was really appreciated, and now the question can be set to answered as well!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply rewrite the query that only products with a productname are returned.

> SELECT * FROM products WHERE productname NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12

Comment: This is actually a good idea, however with the ORDER BY RAND(), it doesn't seem to work.