# Select random fields where consecutive pairs have different foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `A` with a foreign key to table `B` and I need to select 10 random fields from `A` such that fields in consecutive pairs have different `b_id`, i.e. a valid result would be:
`(x1, x2) (x3, x4) ... (xn, xn+1)` where `xi` are the selected fields and if we name `fi` the foreign key of `xi` to `B`, then `fi` should different of `fk+1`. I have tried a really awful query which I don't like at all and I believe slow.

This is my current query:

```
select a1.b_id, a1.x, a2.b_id, a2.x
from A a1, A a2
where a1.b_id <> a2.b_id
order by rand()
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is good with the exception of `order by rand()`, which will assign a random value to all of your rows, and then order them all before fetching the first 5. This is very expensive when you only really need 5 rows. This question has more efficient methods for getting random rows from MySQL: [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

After you generate this two column query, you can transform it into a single column query by:

1. save the result in a temporary table
2. union the first column to the second column, marking where it came from
3. select from the union in order

I have include an example below. Replace the insert line with your query.

```
create temporary table x (
  x1 int, x2 int);

insert x values (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6) ,(7, 8), (9, 10);

select v 
from (
  SELECT
    x1 AS v,
    1 AS pairPosition,
    @curRow1 := @curRow1 + 1 AS row_number
  FROM x
  JOIN    (SELECT @curRow1 := 0) r

  UNION

  SELECT
    x2 AS v,
    2 AS pairPosition,
    @curRow2 := @curRow2 + 1 AS row_number
  FROM x
  JOIN    (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r
) xx
order by xx.row_number asc, pairposition asc
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have a new problem which could be asked as a new question: I need to select the pairs as a single column, i.e. `x1, x2, x3, x4, ... xn, xn+1`, not as two as my original question. Any idea?

Comment: @e.campver I've updated my answer with a crude method to change the 2 column solution into a single column. Unfortunately I had to use a temporary table since the solutions (unpivot, cte, or temporary variable) I had in mind are not in MySQL. Even the row number is ugly.