# Randomizing in MySQL but only pulling 'active' rows

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT name
  FROM random AS r1 JOIN
       (SELECT (RAND() *
                     (SELECT MAX(id)
                         FROM random)) AS id)
        AS r2
 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id
 ORDER BY r1.id ASC
 LIMIT 1;
```

While looking up optimization for MySQL, I have came up with this query.  But, it doesn't entirely serve my purpose because I want to pull random users from my database, but I also have a field for active.  So I want to ensure that "active = 1", but I'm not sure where I would plug that into this query to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT name
FROM random r1
JOIN (SELECT RAND()*MAX(id) randid
      FROM random
      WHERE active = 1) r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.randid
AND r1.active = 1
ORDER BY r1.id
LIMIT 1
```

You need to test `active = 1` in both the subquery and the main query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

While there are [more optimized alternatives to `RAND()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function), I'd encourage you to simplify your query starting with the above and optimize later.

Comment: Based on the research I've done (been looking for about 2 hours), this offers performance issues so I was going to avoid using it.

Comment: Yes. Depending on the number of active records, indexes, etc the above may still be more efficient than your nested queries.

Comment: I will use it for the time being then - Until I need to optimize it more. Still open to suggestion though.

Comment: It's good to think about optimization. But not to the point where you're losing hours of work over it. Nonetheless, there are several answers in the link above.