# Optimize multiple JOINs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, outer-join

I have this MySQL which should be correct syntax:

```
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
 c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
 l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
 l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
 l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
 l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
 l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
 l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
from j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l 
LEFT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON (cf.link_id = l.link_id),
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
UNION ALL
select c.cat_id,c.cat_name as cat_name, 
 c.cat_desc, c.cat_image, mi.filename, 
 l.link_id, l.user_id, l.address,l.city, 
 l.country,l.link_created,l.link_desc, 
 l.email,l.fax,l.link_hits, l.link_modified,
 l.link_name,l.postcode, l.price,l.link_rating, 
 l.state,l.telephone,l.link_votes,
 l.website, l.link_id, l.link_visited, cf.value
FROM j25_mt_cats as c,
j25_mt_links as l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf ON cf.link_id = l.link_id,
j25_mt_images AS mi,
j25_mt_cl as cl
where cf.cf_id = 40 and cl.link_id = l.link_id 
 AND mi.link_id = l.link_id AND mi.ordering < 2  
 AND c.cat_id = cl.cat_id and c.cat_published = 1 
 AND c.cat_approved = 1 and l.link_published = 1 and l.link_approved = 1
 AND cf.link_id IS NULL;
```

The query eats up 3GB+ in the tmp directory and ends up timing out. I'm missing something here, how can I increase the efficiency? My goal here was just adding onto an existing query to grab a value from an additional table (j25_mt_cfvalues).

`explain`:

```
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra            |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | mi         | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |  165 |                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | c          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     |  301 |                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | l          | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | 2139 |                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | cf         | ref   | link_id       | link_id | 4       | db_table.l.link_id |    2 |                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | cl         | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                     | 2742 | Using index      |
|  2 | UNION        | NULL       | NULL  | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | NULL | Impossible WHERE |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | NULL |                  |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+------------------+
```

j25_mt_cats schema:

> CREATE TABLE `j25_mt_cats` (
>     `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>     `cat_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `cat_desc` text NOT NULL,
>     `cat_parent` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_links` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_cats` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_featured` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `cat_published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     `cat_approved` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_template` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
>     `cat_usemainindex` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `cat_allow_submission` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
>     `cat_show_listings` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
>     `metakey` text NOT NULL,
>     `metadesc` text NOT NULL,
>     `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `lft` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `rgt` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`cat_id`),
>     KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`,`cat_published`,`cat_approved`),
>     KEY `cat_parent` (`cat_parent`,`cat_published`,`cat_approved`,`cat_cats`,`cat_links`),
>     KEY `dtree` (`cat_published`,`cat_approved`),
>     KEY `lft_rgt` (`lft`,`rgt`),
>     KEY `func_getPathWay` (`lft`,`rgt`,`cat_id`,`cat_parent`),
>     KEY `alias` (`alias`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3851 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

j25_mt_links schema:

> CREATE TABLE `j25_mt_links` (
>     `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>     `link_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `alias` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `link_desc` mediumtext NOT NULL,
>     `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_hits` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_votes` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_rating` decimal(7,6) unsigned NOT NULL default '0.000000',
>     `link_featured` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_approved` int(4) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_template` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `attribs` text NOT NULL,
>     `metakey` text NOT NULL,
>     `metadesc` text NOT NULL,
>     `internal_notes` text NOT NULL,
>     `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `link_created` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     `publish_up` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     `publish_down` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     `link_modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     `link_visited` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `state` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `telephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `fax` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `website` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>     `price` double(9,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
>     `lat` float(10,6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Latitude',
>     `lng` float(10,6) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Longitude',
>     `zoom` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Map''s zoom level',
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`link_id`),
>     KEY `link_rating` (`link_rating`),
>     KEY `link_votes` (`link_votes`),
>     KEY `link_name` (`link_name`),
>     KEY `publishing` (`link_published`,`link_approved`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`),
>     KEY `count_listfeatured` (`link_published`,`link_approved`,`link_featured`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`,`link_id`),
>     KEY `count_viewowner` (`link_published`,`link_approved`,`user_id`,`publish_up`,`publish_down`),
>     KEY `mylisting` (`user_id`,`link_id`),
>     FULLTEXT KEY `link_name_desc` (`link_name`,`link_desc`)
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3229 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

j25_mt_cfvalues schema:

> CREATE TABLE `j25_mt_cfvalues` (
>     `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>     `cf_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `link_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>     `value` mediumtext NOT NULL,
>     `attachment` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
>     `counter` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
>     KEY `cf_id` (`cf_id`,`link_id`),
>     KEY `link_id` (`link_id`),
>     KEY `value` (`value`(8))
>   ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20876 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

Comment: Show us the EXPLAIN output and the table schemas. ORDER BY RAND() is probably your main problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function

Comment: @Martin Sorry about that, added the explain. Tried without the rand() and had same issue. I'll start editing the schemas in now.

Comment: @Zeno: hint: look at the `possible_keys` + `key` columns in `EXPLAIN`. Thoughts?

Comment: @Martin Added schema, formatting came out a bit bad. I'll try to clean it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your first SQL query does not have any WHERE criteria and is causing a global cartesian across EVERY table your are working.  Only in the second query does the WHERE clause get applied.

That said, you had a left and right join for the CF table, but you can't have both a cf=40 and cf IS NULL, so I simplified to just a left join on the ID AND 40... so if there IS a record in the CF table it only shows if it's value is 40... any other value would be ignored..

that said, your query can be simplified down to a single query.  I also changed to JOIN syntax instead of WHERE so you and others can see the relation to the tables vs guessing.

```
select 
      (all your fields)
   from 
      j25_mt_cats as c
         JOIN j25_mt_cl as cl
            ON c.cat_id = cl.cat_id 
            JOIN j25_mt_links as l 
               ON cl.link_id = l.link_id 
               AND l.link_published = 1 
               AND l.link_approved = 1
               JOIN j25_mt_images AS mi
                 ON l.link_id = mi.link_id 
                AND mi.ordering < 2  
                LEFT OUTER JOIN j25_mt_cfvalues AS cf 
                   ON l.link_id = cf.link_id
                   AND cf.cf_id = 40
   where
          c.cat_published = 1 
      AND c.cat_approved = 1 
   ORDER BY 
      RAND() DESC;
```

TO help optimize the query, your

```
j25_mt_cats should have an index on (cat_published, cat_approved)
j25_mt_cl on (cat_id)
j25_mt_links on (link_id, link_published, link_approved)
j25_mt_images on (link_id, ordering)
j25_mt_cfvalues on (link_id, cf_id)
```

Comment: A side note: the mysql **may** rearrange `FROM` and `INNER JOIN` tables. In that case the proposed indexes won't be enough/heplful.

Comment: In that case, I would add the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" do to in the order proposed.

Comment: ... or just used proper indexes :-) Optimizer (in most cases) knows better what is better for it.

Comment: @zerkms, correct--- in MOST cases, however, working with a large table of government grants and contracts of 15+ million and without the STRAIGHT_JOIN, KILLED a query I was working... adding it completed the query in about 2 hrs.

Comment: "15+ million", "large table"... /me smiles. Well, it's an offtop anyway.