# Speeding up a query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table which has over 1 million rows and could get bigger. I have a python script which queries the database to grab one random record from this database table. The query I am using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE cust_type = 'C'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

I was simply wondering if there is a better, faster way to do this?

Thanks to Michael Benjamin for his excellent answer:
Below is my working Python script with his suggestions

```
def util_get_random_customer_individual():
    # Gets a random customer from the MySQL DB Customers table. Users will need to parse items from the results into
    # individual results
    # Connect to the DB
    config = {'user': 'user', 'password': 'password', 'host': 'host name',
              'port': 3306, 'database': 'database'}
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    c = conn.cursor()
    type_code = 'I'
    # Get a random customer based on the the count
    c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE cust_type = %s', type_code)
    count = c.fetchone()[0]
    random_value = random.randint(1, count)
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE cust_type = %s LIMIT %s, 1', (type_code, random_value,))
    random_customer = c.fetchone()
    return random_customer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Randomly generating a number based on the total, then using the offset is extremely quick.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM customers 
WHERE cust_type='C';
```

PHP:

```
$rand = rand(1, $count);

SELECT * 
FROM customer 
WHERE cust_type='C' 
LIMIT $rand, 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in MySQL. Doesn't like the `LIMIT number, number`

Comment: What is your MySQL version? [MySQL 4.1+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html) supports it.

Comment: What version of mysql are you running? Older versions might require `LIMIT 1 OFFSET ####`

Comment: I'm running 5.0.22, on Redhat Linux

Comment: This works for me. I had to tweak the PHP a little since I am using Python, however this works really well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
WHERE id >= 
(SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM customers ) 
AND cust_type = 'C'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That returns "Invalid use of group function"