# PHP Yii criteria select random records with limit

Tags: php, yii, criteria

I have 1000 questions in the Question Model.
How do I select 50 questions out of the 10000 randomly using Yii criteria ??

I am using Mysql as the Db

So far I have tried with the following

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->limit = 50;
$criteria->select = array('id');
$criteria->addCondition('chapter = xyz');
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using MySQL then it's:

```
$criteria->order = 'RAND()';
```

(updated from @topher answer)

Using this technique on a large number of rows will take a long time ([source](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/)):

> As soon as you have 10000 rows the overhead for sorting the rows
>   becomes important.

In this case, refer to these answers:

- [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)
- [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution: mysql's order by rand

```
$criteria->order('RAND()');
```

However from http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

> As soon as you have 10000 rows the overhead for sorting the rows becomes important.

How to efficiently get random rows has been already been answered: [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Answer (score 0):

```
$criteria->order(array('RAND()'));
```

Comment: It is important to point out, that [using `ORDER BY RAND()` is wrong](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/)!