# How do I optimize my RAND() function for large tables?

Tags: mysql

I need to get 20 random images from a table
My current query is

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20;
```

This question might help but his query is much more complicated, I understand the answers since im a beginner
[How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function?rq=1)

Comment: I updated my answer with that but his query is too complex

Comment: I only need to select everything and return an x amount

Comment: That's because you problem _is complex_. That is: despite problem has very short description, it's not the thing that can be easily solved in mysql

Comment: Ok I will do my research and update my answer with the solution specific for a simple query like this

Comment: [Try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance problem with your query is not the `rand()` per se but the `order by` on a large number of rows.  If you know that foo has a certain number of rows, say 1,000,000, then something like this will run much faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE RAND() < 0.00001
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```

The `where` clause reduces the number of rows for the `order by` to about 100.  And, you would be very confident that the number would be at least 20.  You can automate this calculation as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo cross join
     (SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM foo) const
WHERE RAND() < 100.0/cnt
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20;
```