# Use PHP mt_rand() instead of MySQL rand() to avoid slow query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP file that looks for a random id from a MySQL DB, but when the table is big enough it gets slow.
**ID row has gaps.**

Original

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM definiciones ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
```

Idea

```
$random = mt_rand(0, 10000);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM definiciones WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM definitiones WHERE id < $random)";
```

I know the exact amount of rows in the DB beforehand. Is it a good idea to replace the original query?

Comment: Your question has peaked my curiosity, why are you ordering by a random number? Is it really necessary or isn't there a better way to do the entire thing?

Comment: With gaps in the id values, it is possible that you could get no results from the query if there were no remaining `id` values below some number.

Comment: @BobbyAxe It was made that way to get a random result, but it was a very ineficient way to achieve it.

Comment: @Nick You are right about that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1244555/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/2943403

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORDER BY RAND() function taking long time to execute in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313771/order-by-rand-function-taking-long-time-to-execute-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good idea to replace the original query?

Yes, but there's a simpler way of expressing this:

```
SELECT * FROM definiciones WHERE id >= ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

With `?` set to a random number between 0 and the maximum ID in the table.

---

Now, an improvement: If there are any gaps in the values of `id`, the results from the previous method will be skewed somewhat. (For instance, if there are no rows with `id < 100`, then a row with `id = 100` will be selected much more often than one with `id = 101`.) You can avoid this by using a separate column for randomization. First, you will need to add the column:

```
ALTER TABLE definiciones ADD COLUMN randomval FLOAT NOT NULL,
                         ADD KEY randomval (randomval);
UPDATE TABLE definiciones SET randomval = RAND();
```

Then, to select a fairly chosen random item:

```
SELECT * FROM definiciones WHERE randomval > ? LIMIT 1;
```

using a random value between 0 and 1 for the parameter.

There is a small chance that this will return no rows (if `RAND()` selects a value greater than the highest value in the table). If this happens, repeat the query.

You will need to set `randomval = RAND()` when inserting new rows into the table.