# How can I mix mysql results?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to mix mysql result?

For example I have these results in my database table

```
id  | data
-----------
1   | data 1
2   | data 2
3   | data 3
   ...
N   | data N
```

And I want the data to be shown in random.

For example

```
data 1
data 3
data 2
data 6
```

I hope it was easy to understand me, sorry if something in my question is not clear.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try :

select ... from table where ... orderBy rand() ;

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by `RAND` with hash that is under your control, also it will reset with each select and also it will eat up much less resources, just add to your `SELECT` statement `ORDER BY MD5( CONCAT( id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) )`

Tested it on table that has over 2 mln rows and works like a charm.