# Optimize MySQL random when using ordering by two parameters

Tags: mysql, random

I need to get some data from tables and order them by two parameters. One of the parameters are RAND() because records needs to be random. I have large database and using RAND() slows down performance alot and I want to avoid it. Is there any chance to optimize performance of random ordering ? I need to order my result based on count (lowest to highest) and then I need to perform ordering by RANDOM.

This is query that I am using

```
SELECT c.username, IF(s.Broj IS NULL,0,s.Broj) as Ukupno
FROM user AS c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS Broj
  FROM odis
  GROUP BY username
) AS s
ON c.username = s.username
ORDER BY s.broj ASC, RAND()
```

Comment: Are you sure that `rand()` is slowing down the query and not the `order by`?

Comment: ordering by RAND() is slowing my query @GordonLinoff . when I remove rand from ordering it goes well

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the query with and without the `RAND()`.  I, too, am puzzled by why RAND is the villain.

Answer (score 0):

I actually doubt very much that the `rand()` is slowing down the query much more than the `order by` would.  But, you can put the `rand()` in the subquery, which should do the same thing:

```
SELECT c.username, coalesce(s.Broj, 0) as Ukupno
FROM user c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT username, COUNT(*) AS Broj, rand() as r
      FROM odis
      GROUP BY username
     ) s
     ON c.username = s.username
ORDER BY Ukupno ASC, r
```

Note that `r` will have `NULL` values when there is no match.  For this group, the ordering may not be as random as you would like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I remove ordering by RAND my query runs 100 times faster . on 200 records, without rand query runs for 0.0003 seconds. But when I use rand execution time is 0.0435 seconds . That's only 200 records. What if there's a 10x times more rows ...

Comment: 0.0003 seconds smells like it came from the Query cache.  Please try it again, but with SELECT **SQL_NO_CACHE** ...

Comment: @RickJames . . . Or it sounds like `s.broj` has an index.