# Is this fastest way to get random records in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

NOTE : Yes! there are number of related questions to this.But I have unique approach which is not mentioned in any other post and I want to know if it is fast.

So all other questions have accepted answer as below

```
SELECT * FROM catalogue order by RAND() LIMIT 5
```

But I heard it is too slow for large table.So I want to know if below approach is faster than above code.

```
//I know my row count.500k
<?php
$rand = rand(1,499990)
$limit = "$rand , ",$rand+10;
```

and my query wil be

```
SELECT * FROM catalogue  LIMIT $limit
```

where `$limit` will be like `1,10` , `450,460` etc...

Comment: Your code will work to extract random number of records.

Comment: You could test with microtime() : http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function