# MYSQL: Query order by rand() very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have to pick 30 random records from a table, except that the query uses one second, and this slows mysql if the content is displayed by many users.
This is the query:

```
SELECT relationship, COUNT(id) AS number FROM FR_user_friends GROUP BY relationship ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 30
```

Do you know how to speed up this query? Thank you.

If I remove rand() the query is fast. We have to find an alternative for rand()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Comment: I think u need index on `relationship` column

Comment: It is already indexed.

Comment: Just curious. Could you run rand() over the result of a subquery of the joined data and speed things up?

Answer (score 10):

ORDER BY RAND() causes the engine to generate random values for all rows, so if you want to select a few rows from a large table, it gives very bad performance.

You could for example generate 30 random values in php in the range [1, maximum row-id] and select the first row with a row-id that is bigger or equal to the random value with `LIMIT 1`.

An SQL-only way to deal with this you find in *chris*' answer below and in more detail in  [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function) (but some are not trivial as well).

Comment: Yes,  I can.  ;-P But SO is not a coding service, but for help with specific questions. So I would suggest that you give it a try by yourself first.

Answer (score 4):

the `RAND()` function is too slow and consumes too much CPU. it generates a random number for every row and picks the smallest one so that's why it's so slow.

For speed up you can generate a random number in PHP and use in `LIMIT`
 clause like this:

```
$firstClauseLimit = rand(0,20); // create an int random number between 0 to 20

"... ... LIMIT $firstClauseLimit,1"
```

by this way, it will be so faster.

Answer (score 4):

This query should be much faster than your

```
SELECT relationship, id 
FROM FR_user_friends fr1 
JOIN (
  SELECT CEIL(RAND() * ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM FR_user_friends )) AS id ) AS fr2 
  ON fr1.id >= fr2.id 
  LIMIT 0,30
```

I also suggest read more here: [What would be faster?](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,163708,163752#msg-163752)