# AWS RDS MySQL approximately 8 million rows

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-rds, cpu-usage

So I've hosted a video sharing website and right now I have approximately 2 million rows stored in an AWS RDS `db.t2.large`. The pricing for this instance is `$0.136/hr`. However it is very slow because it only has 2 CPU's. The cost to get an instance with 8 CPUs is `$0.544/hr` which is well over my budget. I am running the statement `"SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100"` on almost every page and it is too slow with only 2 CPU's. With 8 CPU's it is bearable. How do I make this faster? I don't want users waiting a long time every on refresh or new link. The number of rows is expected to grow 8 million rows when i complete the data dump.

[--- AWS RDS DB CPU ---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp2Ra.png)

[--- AWS RDS DB Pricing ---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcsSY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it perhaps enough to just select randomly from within a date range, or from videos that have a certain amount of views?  What database are you on? See e.g. [MYSQL: Query order by rand() very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659076/mysql-query-order-by-rand-very-slow)

Another approach is to cache the randomized values. You can do it in a way that looks completely random to each user:

> user A requests random sample => store sample in cache, and mark it as
> having been retrieved by A
>
> user B requests random sample => get random sample from cache,
> checking whether we have retrieved it before (we haven't, it was A, so
> return it)
>
> user A requests random sample => get random sample from cache,
> checking whether we have retrieved it before (we have, it was us, so
> we do another request and add it to the cache and then return it)

This makes the request of B "free", so instead of 3 requests we only have 2.

Comment: I like this idea of cache random values. Everyday I can set a process to create the table that contains the videos that should be displayed to the users loading the web pages. Then I retrieve these rows whenever someone reloads or hits a new link.

Comment: I also thought of ... generating the random ID's in the code as opposed to making the SQL engine do so. Then run 100 `SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = %%%`. What do you think?

Comment: @ExAmazonIntern I'd try that as well, but I haven't benchmarked it. You'll have to account for missing IDs if you delete records, though. In the worst case, you'll miss all of the records with the query. See the link I posted, and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function