# Updating query to reflect normalized database

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I am trying to make an article website, but I want to normalize my current database. I have four tables each labeling a category except for one. The four tables are: Entertainment, Lifestyle, Science, and Articles. Articles is the combination of all the entries of Entertainment, Lifestyle, and Science. I want to delete Entertainment, Lifestyle, and Science and just leave the Articles table, thus saving space and increasing performance. The only problem I am facing though is with a query that generates random articles by getting the last ID of the table, and then getting a random number between 6 and the max ID.

All my tables have the following structure: `id` (unique), `category` (the type of article this is, i.e Entertainment), `title` (title of the article), `image` (image URL of the article), `link` (URL of the article), `Counter` (number of views this article has), and `dateStamp` (the date the article was published). Here's the query I am trying to update based on my normalized database.

```
<?php
  //SELECT the MAX id from the Entertainment table
    $MAX_ID = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Entertainment");

  //Get Max id value
    $MAX_ID = $MAX_ID->fetch_array();
    $MAX_ID = $MAX_ID[0];

   //Create random number variable
    $RAND_NUM;

  //If the Max ID is less than 6, make $MAX_ID the $RAND_NUM
    if ($MAX_ID < 6) {
        $RAND_NUM = $MAX_ID;

    } 

  //Else get a random value between 6 and the Max ID
    else {
        $RAND_NUM = mt_rand(6, $MAX_ID);

    }

  //Grab 6 articles by descending from the random number, example: If $RAND_NUM is 7, get all entries from 7-2
    $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Entertainment WHERE id <= $RAND_NUM ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6");

    if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
      //Booleans to check where we are at in the print off
        $conditional  = true;
        $conditional2 = true;
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()) {
            $image = $rows["image"];
            $title = $rows["title"];
            $link  = $rows["link"];
            $count = number_format($rows["Counter"]);

           //Print off these articles on the left
            if ($conditional == true && $conditional2 == true) {
                echo "<div class='left'><a href='$link'><img src=$image><p>$title</p></a><p id='article-views'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fire'></span> $count Views</p></div>";

                $conditional2 = false;
            }

           //Print off these articles on the right
            else {
                echo "<div class='right'><a href='$link'><img src=$image><p>$title</p></a><p id='article-views'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-fire'></span> $count Views</p></div><hr>";

                $conditional2 = true;
            }


        }

        echo "</div>";
    }


?>
```

How should I change/update this query to make it so that I get random Entertainment articles from the Articles table? I am open to any changes that improve the performance of the query as well.

Comment: FYI, your old method assumed that low-numbered article IDs were never deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selecting a random ending ID, just randomize all the rows and select 6 from them.

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE category = 'Entertainment'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

If you need to avoid `ORDER BY RAND()` because it doesn't perform well enough, see [How can i optimize MySQL's ORDER BY RAND() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244555/how-can-i-optimize-mysqls-order-by-rand-function)

Comment: I heard that ORDER BY RAND() is horrible with performance, that's why I've been avoiding it.

Comment: That's true. See the question I linked to.

Comment: Is your table large enough that it's really causing a performance problem, or are you just assuming it will. Don't assume, measure it.

Comment: Right now ORDER BY RAND() would work perfect because the table is small, but 3 months or so I know it will cause problems, that's why I want to have a fully functional query that'll optimize on performance in the long run